prove $\log(x)=o(\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}})$ as $x\rightarrow 0$
I know that I have to verify a limit , but I want to give a different approach
$1$ is it correct to say this?
$\log(x)\leq x^{\alpha}$, $\forall \alpha>0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$
so $x=1/t$, $t\rightarrow 0$ and I have $\log(\frac{1}{t})\leq\frac{1}{x^a}$ thus $-\log(t)\leq\frac{1}{t^a}$ so $\log(t)\leq\frac{1}{t^a}$
the last line where I changed sign is something is threatening me I think it's right because  -log is positive so log is negative.
I chose this proof because I already know that   $\log(x)\leq x^{\alpha}$, $\forall \alpha>0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ please if you provide a better solution start from here

Prove it as a limit ... $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\log x}{1/x^a} = 0$$

$\log(x)≤x^\alpha \forall \alpha >0$ is not true....am I missing something? Can you please explain why you wrote this? (Example in includes x=4 and $\alpha=0.1$)

@Gwen - you are missing the "as $x\to\infty$" clause, which I presume to mean "for sufficiently large $x$". I.e., that for any $\alpha$, there is an $N$ such that if $x > N$, then $\log x \le x^\alpha$.
